# Scrapy doesn't scrape items from my URLs : Crawled (200) / Referer : None

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to **scrape** several pages from a website. For this, I've got different start URLs and a method to crawl the next pages.
The issue is that the spider doesn't **scrape** the items and doesn't seem to crawl indicated pages. I've got no outcome.
Do you have any idea to solve this ?

**Here is the code**

```
    class ListeCourse_level1(scrapy.Spider):
        name = nom_robot
        allowed_domains = domaine
        
        start_urls = url_lister()
        print(start_urls)
        print('-----------------------------')
    
        def parse(self, response):    
            
            selector = Selector(response)    
            
            for unElement in response.xpath('//*[@id="td-outer-wrap"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr'): 
                loader = ItemLoader(JustrunlahItem(), selector=unElement)
                
                loader.add_xpath('eve_nom_evenement', './/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()')
                loader.add_xpath('eve_date_deb', './/td[1]/div/text()')
loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(string) 
                loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            
                yield loader.load_item()
```

**Extract of the shell window**

```
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
2018-02-26 14:13:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-malaysia/page/9/> (referer: None)
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
2018-02-26 14:13:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-malaysia/page/7/> (referer: None)
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
2018-02-26 14:13:21 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-malaysia/page/2/> (referer: None)
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
2018-02-26 14:13:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-02-26 14:13:22 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 6899,
 'downloader/request_count': 21,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 21,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 380251,
 'downloader/response_count': 21,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 12,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 9,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 13, 13, 22, 63002),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 22,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 12,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 20,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 20,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 20,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 20,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 26, 13, 13, 17, 308549)}
2018-02-26 14:13:22 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)

(C:\Users\guichet-v\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3) C:\Users\guichet-v\Documents\CHALLENGE\02_TRAVAIL\ETAPE_1_WebToSGBD\SCRIPT\justrunlah>
```

Answer (score 0):

Copying element xpath from your browser's developer tools will give you something that matches only that 1 element.
Even then, browsers sometimes need to modify the html to be able to display it, and since your xpath is super-specific, there's a possibility that you won't get even that 1 match.

How to fix this?

Take a look at the html, find relevant elements, classes and ids, and write an xpath yourself.
For example, something as simple as `//tr` matches all the elements you're trying to match with `//*[@id="td-outer-wrap"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr`.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! Actually it comes from the `tbody` tag, that actually doesn't exist in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

As @stranac said, the issue comes from the Xpath. Currently, when I copied the Xpath of my element in Google console there was a `tbody` tag. But this tag doesn't in the source code. As @gangabass explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49171414/scrapy-tbody-tag-return-an-empty-answer-but-has-text-inside), this is "a common problem: sometimes there is no `tbody` tag in source HTML for tables (modern browsers add it to the DOM automatically)". I removed it, the extraction works, but it doesn't organise as I want (one line for one event) I have all the extract data in one cell.