# Scrapy tbody tag return an empty answer but has text inside

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, scrapy

I try to scrap and crawl a website. The data is in the tbody tag (event names). 
When I check the google console, the tbody tag has text data, but when I try to scrap it it returns an empty answer (also tested in scrapy shell). I checked for an AJAX method, because it can bug the script, but it seems does not have it.

**Do you have any idea why the answer is empty whereas the tbody tag has text inside source code ?**

**Here is my code**

```
nom_robot = 'ListeCAP' 
domaine = ['www.justrunlah.com'] 
base_url = [
    "https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-malaysia",
    "https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-australia",
]

class ListeCourse_level1(scrapy.Spider):
    name = nom_robot
    allowed_domains = domaine
    start_urls = base_url 

    def parse(self, response):    

        selector = Selector(response)

        for unElement in response.xpath('//*[@id="td-outer-wrap"]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr'): 
            loader = ItemLoader(JustrunlahItem(), selector=unElement)
            loader.add_xpath('eve_nom_evenement', './/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()')

        # define processors
            loader.default_input_processor = MapCompose(string) 
            loader.default_output_processor = Join()
            yield loader.load_item()
            yield loader.load_item()
            if response.xpath('//a[@class="smallpagination"]'):
                next_page = response.meta.get('page_number', 1) + 1
                next_page_url = '{}?page={}'.format(base_url, next_page)
                yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse, meta={'page_number': next_page})
```

**The terminal window**

```
['https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-malaysia/', 'https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-australia/']
-----------------------------
2018-03-08 12:34:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: justrunlah)
2018-03-08 12:34:56 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'justrunlah', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'justrunlah.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['justrunlah.spiders']}
2018-03-08 12:34:56 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
NOM TABLE EN SORTIE :
import_brut_['www.justrunlah.com']
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['justrunlah.pipelines.JustrunlahPipeline']
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2018-03-08 12:34:57 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justrunlah.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2018-03-08 12:34:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-malaysia/> (referer: None)
2018-03-08 12:34:58 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justrunlah.com/running-events-calendar-australia/> (referer: None)
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------
                SCRAPING DES ELEMENTS EVENTS
--------------------------------------------------
2018-03-08 12:34:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2018-03-08 12:34:58 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 849,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 76317,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 8, 11, 34, 58, 593309),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2018, 3, 8, 11, 34, 57, 419191)}
2018-03-08 12:34:58 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

**And the scrapy shell**

[image: Scrapy shell]

Comment: What are you trying to select on the page? The initial xpath you're trying to use returns an array of empty objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to select all the event names, if so you can use this as your xpath `//*[@class="cal2table"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()`

So I believe the issue you are having is due to your xpath definitions, without any further information on what you're trying to select this is the best answer I can give.

A tip, you can use the following command in Chrome/Firefox console to test your xpath:
`$x('//*[@class="cal2table"]/tbody/tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()')`

To use this as you currently are trying to load the items in, then try the following snippet instead. I haven't tested this so you may need to make small adjustments.

`for unElement in response.xpath('//*[@class="cal2table"]//tr'): 
        loader = ItemLoader(JustrunlahItem(), selector=unElement)
        loader.add_xpath('eve_nom_evenement', './/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()')`

Comment: Yes you right, I'm trying to scrap all the event names in several URLs and next pages if those exist. I tried your xpath, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try the update I have provided, I can't help any further because I don't have Scrapy on the machine. Otherwise it looks like you're on the right track, just not the correct xpath.

Comment: I tried but it still returns an empty answer.
Thanks for the tip ! It's going to be really useful ! 
I'll continue to search !

Comment: See gangabass answer, I believe the path he has suggested should work. I did a `scrapy fetch <site> > out.html` and inspected the HTML. The `tbody` is indeed missing, so scrapy rendered the page differently.

Comment: Yes I tried, I removed `tbody` tag from my Xpath, but the issue is that all the data is inserted in one cell instead of having one line for one event.

Comment: I updated the `for` loop, you need to iterate over all the `<tr>` and then apply the `.//td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()` relative to the `unElement`. Which is what the `ItemLoader` should be doing.

Answer (score 5):

Just remove `tbody` from you xpath or css expression and it will work.

Modern browsers are known for adding `tbody` elements to tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use `tbody` in your XPath expressions.

Comment: @gangabass Thanks a lot for all your answers! You right, the issue comes from the `tbody` tag, but when I removed it from my Xpath, all the data is inserted in one cell instead of having one line for one event.

Answer (score 4):

It's a common problem: sometimes there is no `tbody` tag in source HTML for tables (modern browsers add it to the DOM automatically). So always check HTML *source* code:

```
//*[@class="cal2table"]//tr/td[2]/div/div[1]/div/a/text()
```